# Pairs $(f,g)$ for which the Riemann-Stiltjes integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,dg(x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, riemann-integration

Let us deal with $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$.

I know that $\int_a^bf(x)\,dg(x)$ exists for $f$ continuous and $g$ of bounded variation.

But is there a way to get *exactly* all the pairs $(f,g)$ for which the Riemann-Stieltjes exists?

Even a good reference, a link, some pdf would be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read it in a few semesters, but Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is a standard source which covers the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Not sure if if contains the exact answer you're looking for, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer since you claim you are not sure if Rudin has the exact answer. Be best to consult Rudin and come back with a citation for that book if it does contain it, although I agree this is the thing the OP is after.